# Using multiple parameters when executing stored procedure using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new to development and SQL but wanted to try and create a simple application that I can use for myself. I created the following stored procedure for a SQL Server 2012 database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddAchievement
    @AchievementName varchar(50),
    @AchievementHeading varchar(50),
    @AchievementPoints varchar(4),
    @AchievementDescription varchar(1000)
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Achievements WHERE AchievementName = @AchievementName)
        UPDATE dbo.Achievements
        SET AchievementName = @AchievementName,
            AchievementHeading = @AchievementHeading,
            AchievementPoints = @AchievementPoints,
            AchievementDescription = @AchievementDescription
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO dbo.Achievements
            SELECT 
                @AchievementName, @AchievementHeading, 
                @AchievementPoints, @AchievementDescription
```

I then wanted to execute this stored procedure inside a windows application I am creating in Visual Studio 2015.

I've added my data set and added a table adapter, which is setup to use this stored procedure.

Here's to code I'm using to execute the procedure:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
Int32 rowsAffected;

cmd.CommandText = achievementsTableAdapter.AddAchievement(txtAchievementName.Text, txtAchievementHeading.Text, txtAchievementPoints.Text, txtAchievementDescription.Text);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

I have four text boxes on my form and the text entered into these will be used as parameters to pass to the stored procedure. I'm sure there are better ways to code this but essentially it works. I am only getting one error and I think it's because the stored procedure is setup to ignore the primary key column.

The error I get is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

None of my parameters are setup as an int, but the table the stored procedure works on does have a primary key that isn't referenced in the stored procedure or code. If the error is pointing to the PK I don't know how to get around this because this is setup so it will automatically increment as each row is added to the table, so I don't want to interact with this through the code or stored procedure.

Can anyone help me identify if it is the PK that the error refers too, and if so how I can get around it? If it isn't the PK does anyone have any suggestions as to why I'm getting an error referencing an int when I'm not using one?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: SqlCommand.CommandText is a string but what returns your AddAchievement ?

Comment: I assumed that is the table adapter he said he created, but he doesn't show where, or how, achievementsTableAdapter is created.

Comment: `None of my parameters are setup as an int` except for `@AchievementPoints tinyint,`

Comment: Apologies, I had entered an older piece of code. I have since changed that variable to a varchar so have updated the code above too.

Comment: The error message says "cannot convert INT to STRING" so there is some piece of code that expects a string but you try to assign an int to it. From the code above the only possible culprit is the return value of AddAchievemtn assigned to CommandText- I suggest to remove everything related to SqlCommand and use only the call to AddAchievement

Comment: The stored procedure doesn't return a value and the query added to the table adapter is set to return no value.

Comment: Would you like to try: _Int32 rowsAffected = achievementsTableAdapter.AddAchievement(txtAchievementName.Text, txtAchievementHeading.Text, txtAchievementPoints.Text, txtAchievementDescription.Text);_  and comment out all the code relative to the SqlCommand?

Comment: Thank you so much Steve. That worked a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve commented on my question with a solution that resolved my error. The code executed on my button click is now as follows:

```
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=****;Password=****");
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        Int32 rowsAffected = achievementsTableAdapter.AddAchievement(txtAchievementName.Text, txtAchievementHeading.Text, txtAchievementPoints.Text, txtAchievementDescription.Text);
        sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Do you really need to create/open/close the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AcheivementPoints is set up in the proc to take tinyint, but you are trying to pass it to the adapter as text.